# Can't run python on Mac

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip

I am fairly new to python.I am literally on learning process.  I know it sounds stupid, but any help will be appreciated. 
I type just python on Terminal, I am having this error:

```
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

I want to install or uninstall packages. I typed  pip install matplotlib
I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't relevant to programming python, but to installing python on mac

Comment: you have already started an interpreter

Comment: You are *already running Python* - you need to `exit()` to get back to the Terminal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run `python` in the python interpreter, rather than the command prompt

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
>>> pip install matplotlib
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install matplotlib
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Type `quit()` or `Ctrl+D` to exit from the python interpreter and then you could do the `pip install`, etc